# Enable Tracing in CRM

Tags: sql-server, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I am trying to import customizations over to my server machine that is running Dynamics CRM 4. I am able to upload the customizations file on my CRM and it shows me all the entities.

However when I try to Import these entities CRM gives me an SQL Server error.
I need to get the details of the error and therefore I need to Enable tracing on the CRM server.

How do you enable tracing on Dynamics CRM? I have found quite many pages when I googled the term but I didn't quite get what i was looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a Diagnostic Tool for 4.0 that enables tracing within CRM for you. Enabling tracing causes CRM to emit a ton of debug/error information and is definitely the first step we take when troubleshooting non-trivial issues. Often times the error will tell you exactly what's wrong.

You can get the diag tool from the CRMTools.zip link [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/emeadcrmsupport/archive/2010/04/13/crm-support-tools-hosted-by-the-emea-dynamics-crm-support-blog.aspx).  You'll want the CRMDiagTool4.zip file.  Extract the contents of CRMDiagTool4.zip onto your CRM server and run the CrmDiagTool4.exe.  From the dropdown menu, choose "Dynamics CRM Server".  Click the first button to enable tracing.  Enabling tracing is a huge performance hog, so enable it right before you start your import and disable it right after the error occurs.

To help you read the output, there's a [CRM Trace File Viewer](http://www.stunnware.com/crm2/topic.aspx?id=TraceLogViewer) that lets you filter by message type. Reading the logs without it would be extremely painful. Open the viewer on the server and point it to one of the trace files that was generated (if you installed CRM to the default directory, those will be located in C:\Program Files\Microsoft CRM\Trace).  Finally, filter the log entries down to warnings or worse by choosing Filter -> Log Level -> Warning. (A [fancier version](http://www.stunnware.com/crm2/topic.aspx?id=Framework9) of the viewer is available as a part of the helpful and free [Stunnware Tools](http://www.stunnware.com/?area=products&group=swtools4).)

Good luck!